# Sending output to STDOUT in perl while executing a command

Tags: perl, io, stdout, perl-module

I am writing a perl code to upload code from a repro to a directory(`jsvn update .` a shell comand in my case) . I wanted that while the check in is going on, the result should display in stdout ('jsvn update .' does show that but i have to keep on looking at the monitor in case of any error and incase of error i have to give a clean up and start the process again.) I wrote a program for that, but it doesnot displays output to screen. The cursor keeps blinking and i know the process is going on background, but i want to have the results also displayed to stdout. Please help me.

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use Capture::Tiny qw/tee/;


sub code(){

`jsvn cleanup .`;

($stdout, $stderr, @result) = tee { system( "jsvn update ." ) };

print "@result\n";

}

code();

if($stderr){

code(); 

}else{
print "The checkout has been done successfully \n";

exit;
}
```

Comment: use `IPC::System::Simple qw[ capture ];` instead: `my @result = capture('jsvn update .');`

Comment: But there are lot of exit values for this jsvn , i am to figure out, almost around 50. So i wanted that in case of any error, the process to start all over again.IPC::System::Simple module needs the error codes to be pre-defined to handle those gracefully or the program dies.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use [IPC::System::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~pjf/IPC-System-Simple-1.25/lib/IPC/System/Simple.pm) you could grab exit values through `$EXITVAL` doing something like this:

```
 ...
use IPC::System::Simple qw[capture $EXITVAL];
use feature qw[switch];
 ...
my @result = capture('jsvn update .');

given ($EXITVAL) {
  when (0) {
    print "Ok\n";
  }

  when (1) {

  }
   ..
  when (N) {

  }
}
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Filippo :) Yes this .pm is helpful... Now writing the code fpr capturing the exit value. Thanks again for your time on this.